# Docker-Compose only looks in /opt/redash

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use a docker-compose.yml file in my current directory /home/brian/zammad/docker-compose.yml

When I run the `docker-compose up` command, however, it tells me no such file in /opt/redash/docker-compose.yml

Well, that's true, because I got rid of Redash.  But Redash has nothing to do with this application, so why is it insistent on trying ony to run that docker-compose.yml file?

I've never seen this before.

Running Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit
Docker-CE version 19.03.11
Docker-Compose version 1.22.0 from apt.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-compose up` and `down` reuse the settings created by the latest `docker-compose` command specific for the directory you are working on (called a Docker Compose *project* whose name you can set by the `-p` flag of `docker-compose`). The settings include the original `docker-compose.yaml` file the project was built on, which will not be re-built on each `up`.

To force rebuilding the whole project based on the current `docker-compose.yaml`, or another file via the `-f` flag, just run `docker-compose` again.